# How to manually apply emphasis on series in echarts bar-graph?

Tags: angular, echarts

I have a echarts bar graph with series of data. When a bar is clicked, emphasis is applied on it. Is there a way to programmatically select one of the series in the bar-graph to apply emphasis on when the graph loads?

[image: Before Emphasis]
[image: Emphasis when clicked]

The options code I have for the bar graph:

```
  options = {
    markPoint: { data: ['Q1'] },
    color: ['#3398DB'],
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'axis',
      axisPointer: {
        type: 'shadow'
      }
    },
    grid: {
      left: '3%',
      right: '4%',
      bottom: '3%',
      containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: [
      {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
        axisTick: {
          alignWithLabel: true,
        }
      }
    ],
    yAxis: [{
      type: 'value'
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'Counters',
      type: 'bar',
      barWidth: '50%',
      data: [3,8,12,5],
      itemStyle: {
        //highlight
        emphasis: {
          barBorderColor: 'red',
          barBorderWidth: 2
        }

      }
    }]
  };
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's easy. The Echarts API has two methods with opposite actions:

- [`action.highlight`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.highlight) — set emphasis style to dataPoint.
- [`action.downplay`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.downplay) — cancels highlighting.

**A small example:**

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
    var chartData = [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20];

  var option = {
    tooltip: {},
    legend: {
      data: ['Label']
    },
    xAxis: {
      data: ["Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6"]
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
      name: 'Series',
      type: 'bar',
      data: chartData,
            emphasis: {
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'blue'
                }
            },
    }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
    
    // Current selected dataPoint
    var selectedDataPoint = null;
    
    // Each eteration set another type of 
    setInterval(() => {
        var randomDataPoint = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(chartData.length));
        myChart.dispatchAction({ type: 'highlight', dataIndex: randomDataPoint })
    }, 800)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that does the job. And if you don't mind, can you tell me where can I find documentation for such tasks on eCharts?

Comment: See below, it's just official resources.

Answer (score -1):

- Tutorials:  https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html)
- Components reference: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html
- FAQ https://echarts.apache.org/en/faq.html
- API reference https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html
- Globe reference https://echarts.apache.org/en/option-gl.html
- Awesome Echarts https://github.com/ecomfe/awesome-echarts
- Issues on Github https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues?q=
- Github Gist https://gist.github.com/search?l=JavaScript&o=desc&q=echarts&s=updated
- Search by JSFiddle https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net+Echarts
- Search by Codepen https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io+Echarts
- Echarts Gallery [https://gallery.echartsjs.com/explore.html#sort=rank~timeframe=all~author=all](https://gallery.echartsjs.com/explore.html#sort=rank%7Etimeframe=all%7Eauthor=all)