# Echarts align values with x label categories

Tags: echarts

I have a scatter chart that has categorised x tick labels. There are quite a few, and the chart data points are not aligning to their corresponding category x tick. Any idea how to align them? See below chart snapshot. [image]

I have the following config so far:

```
option = {
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                name: 'x Axis',
                data: ["A", "B", "C"],
                nameLocation: 'middle',
                nameGap: 50,
                nameTextStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12},
                boundaryGap: false,
                splitLine: {
                    show: true,
                    lineStyle: {
                        color: '#999',
                        type: 'dashed'
                    },
                },
                axisLine: {
                    show: false
                },
                axisLabel: {
                    interval: 0,
                    rotate: 30
              },
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'value',
                name: 'y Axis',
                nameLocation: 'middle',
                nameGap: 70,
                nameTextStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12
                }
            },
            dataZoom: [{
                type: 'inside'
            }],
            legend: {
                show: true
            },
            grid: {
                    top: 80,
                    containLabel: true,
                },
            tooltip: {
                trigger: "item"
            },
            series: [
                {
                id: 'Series B',
                type: 'scatter',
                data: [[0.11], [-0.01, 0.08, 8.02], [0.06, 0.0, 0.03]]
                },
                {
                id: 'Series A',
                type: 'scatter',
                data: [[0.99, 12.76, 9.45], [9.45, 14.97], [10.66, 10.74, 10.22]...],
                }]
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols that represent data points is centered actually. Just you see optical distortion and it's easy to check. If we to increase the symbols then distortion should be also increased, right? I did it.

[image: images]

Distortion is disappeared. Why? Because display of you computer have too small granularity to show data points correctly.
[image]

When it happens you software use subpixel rendering for get balance between keeping data point form and its visual right position but result anyway can be distorted because it's impossible to correctly fit the three pixels into two.

In general, it not quite simple the problem and you can [explore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) [the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) [separately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). If you want to compensate the distortion you can use [symbolOffset](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.markPoint.data.symbolOffset) method.

P.S. Also [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64347058/1597964) may be useful for you.

Comment: I understand and thank you, you have answered yet another one of my questions!