# Echars can not render a smooth line when it process alot of data

Tags: json, graph, charts, chart.js, echarts

Im using Echarts to build a line graph and i need it to be smooth. I tried `smooth: true` or `smooth: 1.5` but it does not help when the graph has a lot of data. How to make it work with around 2000 data records?

Here is my code:

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [["12",0],["23",1],["32",1],["40",2],["42",2],["72",3]...],
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true
    }]
};
```

[Brake Echarts graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91HqX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the smooth line then inserted data is incorrect. Try to change data to the simple array, i.e. you data should be like [1,2,3,4,5...].

Comment: it worked. thanks.
So, what's wrong with my data?

Comment: i changed all my data to simple records and it worked.

Comment: The common case is to pass x values to the xAxis.data otherwise the Echarts will calculate xAxis by series[n].data. When you passed 2-dim array with the quoted x values then it probably break calculating xAxes and series. Also most safe way to store data is passing it to the dataset — you will catch all bugs with data before chart will rendered.

Comment: Useful link to the Echarts resources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64347058/1597964