# Echart : line chart reverse legend toggle behaviour

Tags: linechart, echarts, apache-echarts

I want to be able to click on the legend label, it then toggles all the other off and highlight selected one series data. current behaviour hide selected legend series. how i can reverse it?

Comment: Consider marking the answer that you find useful as correct one.

Answer (score 2):

As per [@Sergey Fedorov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65819744/3025856), this can be achieved using the `legendSelect` event. Here's some code to demonstrate how that works:

```
function legendSelection(chart, params) {
    const obj = params.selected;
    const selectAll = Object.values(obj).filter(f=>f).length;
    chart.setOption({ animation: true });

    if (selectAll == 0) {
        // select all on second click
        for (var key in obj) {
            chart.dispatchAction({
                type: 'legendSelect',
                name: key
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Re-select what the user unselected
        chart.dispatchAction({
            type: 'legendSelect',
            name: params.name
        });

        // Deselect everything else 
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key != params.name) {
                var val = obj[key];
                chart.dispatchAction({
                    type: 'legendUnSelect',
                    name: key
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use the above function in your code like this:

```
myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function (params) {
    legendSelection(myChart, params);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me to implement my version. One note though - looping like this through all series will be very slow if there are more than 20+ series. There are additional bulk actions: `legendAllSelect` and `legendInverseSelect`, that can be used to retain performance.

Answer (score 1):

Echarts has API with [events and action](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action). This is [good tutorial](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Events%20and%20Actions%20in%20ECharts) to quick start. In short: you need to listen `legendselectchanged` and with `setOption({series:{...}})` change style or number of series. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64329993/1597964